# Installing supervisord with erpnext

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, supervisord, erpnext

I am a newbie to centos commands and scripting.

*Scenario:*
I have installed ERPNEXT and is working okay on the server but I have to do it manually by doing `./lib/wnfy.py --serve`

What I want to do is to start it automatically using supervisord. I have gunicorn and nginx installed. Upon trying to start supervisord here's the error:

> [root@vps3 etc]# chkconfig supervisord on [root@vps3 etc]# service
>   supervisord start /etc/init.d/supervisord: line 11:
>   ./etc/rc.d/init.d/functionsprog=supervisord: No such file or directory
>   Starting :  daemon --pidfile [ -f ]/etc/init.d/supervisord: line 14:
>   success: command not found /etc/init.d/supervisord: line 14: failure:
>   command not found

I am not yet familiar with how things work. Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed supervisor? Follow,

[Install supervisor](http://supervisord.org/installing.html#installing-to-a-system-with-internet-access)

[Initscripts](https://github.com/Supervisor/initscripts) (use jkoppe ones).

Also for production setup, use gunicorn. Supervisor config for it is,

```
    [program:gunicorn]
    command=gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 -w 2 -t 120 lib.webnotes.app:application
    directory=/path/to/erpnext
    user=erpnext
    process_name=%(program_name)s
    autostart=True
    autorestart=True
    redirect_stderr=True
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir for the help. I will try to add your config on the Supervisord.conf and see what happens.